# Windows Services when do they Actually Start?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I ask this because I am having a problem with my C# project. 
To solve it I know a redesign of my code will suffice, but if Windows Service doesn't start how I think it does then I would need to do more thinking.

Therefore I need this question answered...

When does exactly a Windows Service start, or is this something the developer can choose and if so where exactly in the code can I do that?

More info:

- I know there is Delayed Start... but its not that reliable, with this my Service starts correctly at times and at others it does not. Because it relies on VirtualBox or the HD to set up.
- I tried using a separate thread at Service Startup to give the system time to settle, this solves the problem initially but after further testing realized that if the user wanted to stop my service it becomes into a problem because the thread would still be going active. And creates a bug.

Comment: On windows startup if set, otherwise when the service is started manually, you can do this in code using ServiceController or in windows in the Services.msc snapin console

Comment: Short answer: at system boot, for Automatic. Shortly after, for delayed start. If you're looking for more detail, can you expand your question? What problems are you running into?

Comment: I understand this and know about those advices you mentioned but What is exactly windows startup? After the user logs in? or right in the Windows LogOn Screen?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta updated more info.

Comment: Services can begin starting up before the login screen appears, and can continue after the user logs in. See [When do windows xp services get started?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681999/when-do-windows-xp-services-get-started) (slightly old, yes).

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I read that before, and is the reason why I thought about the thread sleeping for later starting... but is there any way to know when the HardDisk has settle(Startup complete) to start the process if that is the case?

Comment: Services can depend on each other.  If your service depends on a Virtual Machine service, you can make your service dependant upon the VM service and only start after that has started.

Comment: @MystereMan Thanks I'll look into this... I believe Virtual Box doesn't have a service. But it's like ignoring my commands until windows is settle and started.

Comment: Some thoughts in my answer below, but one more question - what, *exactly*, are you waiting for VirtualBox to do, before it's safe for your service to start?

Comment: Also: I don't quite understand what you mean by your second bullet point. Can you expand on that? You can ask threads to stop at any time - just check in your worker thread periodically for a message from the main thread.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta The problem is that the I use p/invoke to create the thread to create the Process because It is not possible to create Process that interact with GUI with C# without p/invoke...So stopping the Process is not that simple, but its possible. I already work it that way but its not neat. The code is horrible and the design looks bad with this solution.

Comment: Yeah, spawning a GUI from a service leads to unhappiness. I don't know much about your requirements or design, but I'd suggest launching a process from your service that creates a GUI, and communicating with it with some kind of IPC, instead of directly interacting with the desktop from the service. Might head off pain now, and down the road.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Yeah this is why I am asking this question of the service because I am redesigning my proyect. I figured out the hard way this is a pain to go.. I mean it does solve one initial problem but brings problems when shutting eveything down... So now I am going with Eventbased. Having the service start and just create an event and start the GUI process from that event forward. And doing the same for shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to know when the HardDisk has settle(Startup complete) to start the process if that is the case?

What you're describing is more or less what [Delayed Start](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/02/02/ws2008-startup-processes-and-delayed-automatic-start.aspx) is for.

> I know there is Delayed Start... but its not that reliable, with this my Service starts correctly at times and at others it does not. Because it relies on VirtualBox or the HD to set up.

Oops. It sounds like you don't *really* want to wait for the hard disk to settle - you want to wait for VirtualBox to finish doing something. And by the time Windows kicks off all your delayed start services, VirtualBox has sometimes finished its work, and sometimes not. So, that's not going to work.

Bring up a property sheet for your service, and click on the *Dependencies* tab. You probably don't have anything listed there. Now, open the "Fax" service, and go to that tab. You'll see that this service depends on the "Telephony" service. Makes sense.

Windows has the same problem as you do - some services depend on others, and Windows needs to make sure everything's done in the proper order. You should do the same. Hopefully, you can wait for a VirtualBox service. If you can, set up your service installer to [properly call out its dependencies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371637%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> This column is a list of names of services or load ordering groups that the system must start before this service. Separate names in the list by Nulls. If the service has no dependencies, then specify Null or an empty string. Use the syntax [~] to insert a Null. Dependency on a group means that this service can run if at least one member of the group is running after an attempt to start all members of the group.

Your installer may automate this process.

Alternatively, more manually, you might just wait, in your Start() method, for something to happen on disk. If you're waiting for a file to get created, for instance, have a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) look for the file, and notify you when it's created.

Comment: Thanks, I get it. It does makes sense. However I am assuming I have the VirtualBox installed. What happens if my end users don't have VirtualBox installed yet and they install my software(my Service) first and reboot making the service start and try to look up that Virtualbox to finish setting up?

Comment: I believe your service will fail to start.

Comment: that is the logical part. I was wondering if it would affect the startup. But you are definitely right. Thanks. Let me try this solution.